# How to give nopasswd access to multiple commands via sudoers?

Tags: sudo, users, administration, restricted-access

Below is what I know:

I have to add this below line in `sudoers` file to give rights to the user for particular task.

```
user_name ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install
```

In this case I want to give access to this user to restart 2 services (i.e. `Apache` and `MySQL`) with all install rights.

Using the above line, I have given him all install rights, now do I have to add same line two more times to give the rights for services? Or can I just add those commands in the same line, separated by comma or something?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I have solved the issue by creating a new group for limited admin rights... name of that group is `LimitedAdmins` after that I updated the `sudoers` file as below.

The line I appended is:

```
%LimitedAdmins ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get*, /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This is the complete `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.    
#   
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of directly modifying   his file.   
#   
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.  
# 
Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL  

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%domain_name\\administrators ALL=(ALL) ALL
%LimitedAdmins ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get*, /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It works perfectly fine in case if your system is domain or not.

Comment: You're not supposed to put stuff after the `#includedir` line are you?

Comment: @hamstar Hey Hi! Yes you are right, thou I have used this configuration file in my company for more than 2 years now & it works perfectly fine. Even thou I would also recommend, to put the last two lines before `#includedir`.

Comment: Or better, put those two lines into a new file under /etc/sudoers.d instead of editing /etc/sudoers.

Comment: @tgharold Yes buddy!! You are right... it is really a better option than what I have suggested... :) Appreciate your idea will try to implement at my place as well.

Comment: Is #includedir a comment?  Or does the include happen automatically and the comment just reminds us of that?

Comment: Yes, it is comment, but we should un-comment it and use that path to make changes to the sudoer's as that is the best option which is suggested by @tgharold

Comment: I don't think you should use apt-get*, the [sudo manual](http://www.sudo.ws/man/sudoers.man.html#x57696c646361726473) advises against using * after commands as they allow _any_ text after the apt-get which might lead to security issues (in my understanding)

Comment: #includedir /etc/sudoers.d is not a comment. It is an actual config parameter. That is why the space is missing after the hash/pound sign. see: http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html

Comment: Pay attention to the blank space before each command and after the comma symbol. It's very important,  otherwise, you will get " /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line XX"

Answer (score 15):

Looks like comma is what you need.

> Cmnd_Alias     PRINTING = /usr/sbin/lpc, /usr/bin/lprm
>   ...
>   user3 ALL= PRINTING

[Source](http://www.garron.me/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)

Comment: I have given rights the way you mentioned it however I got the error message as below.  <br/>E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
  <br/>  E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root? ... can anyone help on this?

Comment: @Rishee I will try once I get home

Comment: my sudores file contains below mentioned things.

Comment: # User privilege specification 
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges 
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL 

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command 
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 


#includedir /etc/sudoers.d 

$ sudo nano /etc/sudoers 
%Domain_Name\\administrators ALL=(ALL) ALL 
%Domain_Name\\user.name ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install, /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I was wondering the same thing as the OP, and it looks like you can as well just duplicate the lines, e.g.

```
user_name ALL=NOPASSWD: cmd1
user_name ALL=NOPASSWD: cmd2
user_name ALL=NOPASSWD: cmd3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the most readable one to me because each line represents each command. So simple.

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing was (Similar to what you are looking for):

```
## PRTG monitoring
Cmnd_Alias PRTG = /bin/cat /proc/loadavg, /bin/df, /var/prtg/scripts/check_proc.sh
prtg ALL = NOPASSWD: PRTG
```

Inside: `/etc/sudoers.d/666-prtg`

(666, because... well... prtg IS a windows based monitoring tool you know)