# allowing user to run systemctl/systemd services without password

Tags: sudo, systemd

I want the default user, `ubuntu` to be able to run a specific service without being prompted for a password.

Specifically `systemctl restart unicorn_my_app.service`.

Have followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246455/how-to-give-nopasswd-access-to-multiple-commands-via-sudoers) to add user `ubuntu` to a newly created group, `LimitedAdmins`, which is confirmed with:

```
$ getent group LimitedAdmins
LimitedAdmins:x:1001:ubuntu
```

Created a new file, `limitedadmins` (using `sudo vim`) in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory containing the following text:

`%LimitedAdmins ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/unicorn_ofn_america restart, /etc/init.d/unicorn_ofn_america start`

I have also tried:

`%LimitedAdmins ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl/unicorn_ofn_america restart, /bin/systemctl/unicorn_ofn_america start`

(And `/bin/systemd`)

Content of `/etc/sudoers/` is the default as confirmed with `sudo visudo` (or `sudo cat /etc/sudoers`):

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

(The hash sign in `#includedir` is not a comment, but part of the [#include directive syntax](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)).

However there's still a password prompt following running `systemctl restart unicorn_my_app.service`

Service is there in the `init.d` directory:

```
$ ls -l /etc/init.d | grep unicorn
-rwxr--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1874 Oct 29 06:47 unicorn_my_app
```

Tried chmodding `755` on the app, but don't think that should make a difference, since `ubuntu` owns it anyway.

Even tried rebooting the system with no difference. Am I missing a step, like a restart/reload)? Configuring something wrong?

I should also mention that I used `vim` to create the new file within `/etc/sudoers.d`, as it seems that the `visudo` command is *only* for editing `/etc/sudoers`.

## UPDATE

Looks like you can edit additional sudo config files with `visudo`. [See below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1354169/288518).

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-system-d-service

Comment: See also this answer for 3 possible solutions to this problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606476/13772 (user service, polkit, sudo).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The sudoers file is fairly flexible, and with that comes complexity. What you want here is to permit access to the command `/bin/systemctl`, with specific parameters:

`%LimitedAdmins ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart unicorn_my_app.service`

Basically you just take the exact command line that you would type, hard-code the path name for safety's sake, and put that into your sudoers file (or `/etc/sudoers.d`). And note that 'start' and 'restart' are completely different as far as sudo is concerned; permitting one won't grant access to the other.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I can copy `/bin/systemctl restart unicorn_my_app.service` directly from the `/etc/sudoers.d/limitedadmins` file and run it in the CLI, and am prompted for a password. Does user `ubuntu` need tp be specified somewhere or does `ALL` open it up to all users for all domains?

Comment: You would run `sudo /bin/systemctl restart unicorn_my_app.service` and it should then run without a password. (posting as comment in case PsiOps's answer is separated from this one)

Comment: @rosuav Is there any way so that we can run it directly like `systemctl restart myapp.service` without using `sudo`.

Comment: Not really, but you could put the command into a script (complete with the sudo prefix), and then put that script onto $PATH. Or make it a shell alias.

Comment: Attention: On other distros `systemctl`  is in `/usr/bin` :-(.

Comment: This was helpful. Also nice to emphasize the differences between start and restart. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend using `sudo visudo` to edit your sudoers file instead of a normal text editor. I hear it's rough to leave that in a wrong state.

Answer (score 7):

I too thought visudo only worked on `/etc/sudoers` but happily, I was mistaken.

`visudo` can be used to modify existing files in `/etc/sudoers.d` or create new ones.  The -f parameter allows this.  If the command is invoked like this:

`visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/permissions_for_subset_of_users`

you can use visudo's validation capabilities to allow safe editing of sudoers.

Also, if you are using some kind of CI/CD or configuration management, you can use `visudo -cf <name_of_file>` to run a validation of the configuration.  (our lead sysadmin provided that second piece of knowledge).

Reference: https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/visudo.man.html