# Ubuntu 16.04 systemd user service anomaly

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I have enabled and started a user service (`systemctl --user enable serviceName`... etc.).
But when I log off, the service stops. Why?
I have made a similar user service on Fedora 22 before, but that doesn't stop when I log off.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

It might be even better:

> The systemd user instance is started after the first login of a user
>   and killed after the last session of the user is closed. Sometimes it
>   may be useful to start it right after boot, and keep the systemd user
>   instance running after the last session closes, for instance to have
>   some user process running without any open session. Lingering is used
>   to that effect. Use the following command to enable lingering for
>   specific user:
>
> ```
> # loginctl enable-linger username
> ```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Systemd user services only last as long as a user's session does. This means you must be logged in for a user service to operate successfully.

In Ubuntu, your session ends when you log out of X, and all terminals (TTYs, local, and remote). I would assume Fedora kept a user session open for you.

For Ubuntu, I would suggest that you create a system-level service and then tell it to run as a specific user. You can do this by setting `User=` and `Group=` in the `[Service]` section of your file. If you want to just have write access on that user account, I would suggest you set appropriate file permissions.

Finally, if you want to make it so that a service starts only when a user tells it to, you can use the instructions [from this AU post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password).

Comment: Not quite.  Per-user services only last as long as the per-user service manager does, an important distinction.  That _might_ be only as long as there's any login session for that user.  But one can configure `systemd-logind` so that that is not the case.